# What is meant by deploying a frontend application if it's executed in a client browser?

Tags: deployment, frontend

The title pretty much sums it up. I understand the idea of bundling all of the packages together and deploying them to a remote server where a client (browser) will download it and execute it.

I have an issue with wrapping my head around the terminology of "deployment" in this scenario. Technically, every client will deploy the frontend application in its own environment every time, or am I missing something? It only needs to have the correct version available on the server to allow for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you'd be deploying it by releasing it to the public (or a group of people). but the browser would just be reading and executing.

So I created a frontend application that just shows hello world.
I published or "deployed" my application to the server.
The client now executes my code and shows hello world.